# Vertical Centering in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out what is the best method in bootstrap 3 to align an element vertically.

I searched in the documentation and i didn't find any special class per the vertical align.

I  would like that the text and the image are align vertically.
any idea?

This is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ttfgL6ns/1/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scenes green">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Moreover, it is more correct to add a div before or after the div with the class row (`<div class "row"`)?

thanks

Comment: Check out: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically Center in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808445/vertically-center-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

using bootstrap you need to configure on DIV parent the`height` before. After that, on DIV child, you use `top:50%` like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="scenes green">
        <div style="height:200px;"> 
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6" style="top: 50%;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: to make it vertically centered, you will have to add `margin-top` with negative margin, equal to the block's height.

Comment: I used a fixed height of the image, so I can use top: 50%. If the image is different of 200px, so this can be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

in your case margin- and padding- of scenes and green classes should drive the alignment style. the answer for better choice between before/after is irrelevant, "rows" just tells to the browser to render a responsive `<table><tr>` and all the children divs found with col- classes are splitted to responsive `<td></td>`

scenes and green styles before the class "row" apply the format to the same elements if declared after

Answer (score 0):

Try with vertical-align: middle property works only for display: table-cell; element. Second thing is vertical align works only for display:inline; elements.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="scenes green">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 display-table-cell">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your css

```
.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-allign: middle;
}
/* just to be sure img is inline */
.display-table-cell img {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add class "col-md-12 col-xs-12" to father of class col-md-6 col-xs-6
Like this:

```
<div class="scenes green col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" />
        </div>
    </div>
```