# How vertically align in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frameworks

I try to vertically align a text in a row, but has no effect.

```
<div class="row direita">
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 description">
        <h4>Modelo</h4>
        <p>Y21512</p>
        <h4>Descrição</h4>
        <p>
            Vestido de Noiva ombro a ombro com transparência no colo e costas, detalhe
            de cinto em cristais, todo em renda francesa rebordada em pedrarias,
            corte sereia com cauda.
        </p>
        <h4>Tamanhos</h4>
        <p>02 – 28</p>
        <h4>Cores</h4>
        <p>Ivory, White</p>
        <h4>Preço</h4>
        <p>R$400.000,00</p>
        <hr />
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary center-block">Comprar</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <img src="img/Produtos Cappeli/Vestido07/Y21512.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-right" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.esquerda {
    display: inline-block;
}

.description {
    /*padding-top: 110px;*/
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I also tried some methods that I found when I searched in Google, but none of them works.

I tried: 
[vertical-align with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)
[How to use vertical align in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192114/how-to-use-vertical-align-in-bootstrap)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertically Center in Twitter Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31808445/vertically-center-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us an example of what you have tried?

This will work on most things

```
.parent {
    display:table;
}
.child {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, to vertically align text using CSS, you have to create a container and then you can use `vertical-align: middle` to align your text

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

---

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <span>Vertically aligned text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to make your parent div relative, and child objects absolute. Then just set the top: 50%, and transform: translateY(-50%) for your child object CSS.